Не обрабатывается callback aiogram 3.x
Хочу добавить к команде /help дополнительный вызов c обычных кнопок(т.е. не Inline) через callback, но почему то callback не обрабатывается, хоть и подключен
Структура:
my_project/
├── main.py
├── keyboards.py
├── callbacks/
|    └── help.py
└── handlers/
     └── base_commands.py

main.py
import asyncio
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.client.default import DefaultBotProperties
from aiogram.enums import ParseMode

from handlers import base_commands
from callbacks import help

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
bot = Bot(token=TOKEN,
          default=DefaultBotProperties(
          parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN_V2
          ))
dp = Dispatcher()

async def main():
    dp.include_router(base_commands.router)
    dp.include_router(help.router)
    
    await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

keyboards.py
from aiogram.types import KeyboardButton
from aiogram.utils.keyboard import ReplyKeyboardBuilder


def get_base_keyboard():
    builder = ReplyKeyboardBuilder()
    builder.row(
        KeyboardButton(
            text='Добавить туннель'),
        KeyboardButton(
            text='Личный кабинет')
    )    
    builder.row(KeyboardButton(
        text='Помощь', callback_data="help")
    )
    return builder.as_markup()

help.py
from aiogram.filters.command import Command
from aiogram.types import Message, CallbackQuery
from aiogram import Router, F

from handlers import base_commands

router = Router()

@router.callback_query(F.data == "help")
async def callbacks_num(callback: CallbackQuery):
    await base_commands.help(callback)

base_commands.py
from aiogram.filters.command import Command
from aiogram.types import Message, CallbackQuery
from aiogram import Router, F

from keyboards import get_base_keyboard

from typing import Union

router = Router()


# Хэндлер на команду /start
@router.message(Command("start"))
async def start(message: Message):
    await message.answer("Текст приветствия", reply_markup=get_base_keyboard())

# Хэндлер на команду /help
@router.message(Command("help"))
async def help(message: Union[Message, CallbackQuery]):
    await message.answer("Текст помощи")

В логах INFO:aiogram.event:Update id=X is not handled. Duration 0 ms by bot id=X.
Пытался по разному менять @router.callback_query(F.data == "help"), но не помогло

По-моему текст ошибки явно говорит о том, что для события Update у Вас нет обработчика. Возможно Вам поможет этот ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79197157/infoaiogram-eventupdate-id-is-not-handled

Обработчик есть и он подключен(main.py), а в примере который вы показали обработчик просто бы не подключен

Попробуйте инициализировать бота bot = Bot(...) внутри main()

Ничего не изменилось, пробовал менять порядок подключения, но тоже ничего

Обычные кнопки не имеют class KeyboardButton не поддерживают callback_data, из-за этого и не работало, т.е. надо было переписать
@router.callback_query(F.data == "help")
как ответ на сообщение
